# Surface area of an oblique cut in Electromagnetism

Tags: algebra-precalculus, geometry, multivariable-calculus, electromagnetism

If anyone is interested, my concern is related to page 176

[Introduction to electrodynamics by Griffiths](http://117.55.241.6/library/E-Books/Electromagnetics%20by%20Griffiths.pdf) 
[image]

Griffiths mentioned that the surface of the oblique cut is the product of surface area at the end $A_{end}$ and $Cos\left ( \theta \right )$. I do not quite understand the intuition involved here. Regardless of an oblique cut, isn't the surface area the same?

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: 1) The area of the oblique cut is the area of the vertical cut **divided** by $\cos{\theta}$ 2) Consider in a cube with side $a$, 2 parallel edges AB and CD at a maximal distance : plane ABDC is a $\pi/4$-orientation cut with area $\sqrt{2}a^2=\dfrac{a^2}{\cos(\pi/4)}$ whereas a vertical orientation gives an area $a^2.$.

Comment: Read more carefully your book: $A_{end}$ is the oblique cut area, while $A$ is the area of the cross section. Thus $A_{end}=A/\cos\theta$. To strengthen your intuition, I'd suggest you to go and cut some slices of a carrot.

Comment: @Aretino: carrots typically are better for conic sections. I would suggest cucumbers instead :)

Comment: @WillieWong Well, cucumbers are not to everybody's taste... ;-)